# build an image that contains ubutnu and redis and mysql

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I want to create a Dockerfile for Gitlab ci to build an image and send it to the docker registry
and then I want to use that image to run my Unit test.
Unit test needs Python and redis and MySQL to run so this image needs to contain all of them.
what can i do?

Comment: `what can i do?` You answered yourself, you can "create a Dockerfile for Gitlab ci to build an image and send it to the docker registry
and use that image to run you Unit test". Why are you writing here? What exactly are you struggling with? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd recommend writing mocks of your data layer that your unit tests can use.  This will make it much faster to run unit tests, and you won't need the Docker external dependency with its various permission concerns.  (If your "unit" tests are really system tests and they're hard to run, developers won't run them, which will lead to frustration.)

Comment: @DavidMaze: Isn't the reason to run CI pipelines remotely as w/ Gitlab CI that you can offload long running builds on some remote system? Otherwise using a remote system to run CI would be counterproductive, as all the tests would be running much faster with a local build as everything is already done properly. And with a remote build, developers must run them, they aren't asked to not run them any longer. This is why the remote pipelines are triggered after push (and trunk you can't push to).

Comment: If a test fails, and the only way I have to run it is to submit a new build to the CI system, reproducing and debugging it will be terrible.  I've stared at code for an hour; submitted a couple of builds with just added debug statements; and eventually realize I've lost a day to a simple variable-shadowing problem, in no small part because I can't do anything without waiting a half hour for the remote CI system to build.  There is definitely room for larger integration tests, which may have container dependencies, but these shouldn't be your default approach.

Comment: Sure, it's daunting. But given the test-suite should run under ten seconds already locally, why first push to a remote system (which takes time), then wait until the workload has been scheduled, then finally run and then still results need to be gathered and finally they become visible (but only after sending some other HTTP request - if only one!) or needing to put focus on some Slack channel to wait for the next distraction?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you want to put Ubuntu and Python and MySQL in 1 Docker Image.

This is possible but a lot of work involving a lot of installing packages in your Dockerfile and entrypoint.

This is not the way Docker is meant to be.

Python and MySQL have already their own images on the Docker Registry.
It's better to make use of those and let them talk to each other via a ProxyServer like NgInx (also a standard Docker Image :-) ).

Then you don't need to create a new Image but make use of all the wonderful standard images in the Docker Registry.

In my company we have everything running in Docker Containers (NodeJS, ReactJS, Python, Postgres, MySQL and Mongo Databases), and we never found the need to create our own images with base software like Python or MySQL. Only use the base image and compile your own code on top of it.

If this tip does not help your use case, I'm interested to know why, and will try to help you.

Comment: we have these containers in a cluster but I want to use this image in the ci process and I can't connect these containers in Gitlab ci.

Comment: Aha, I understand now. I haven't done clusters before, so I will refrain from new tips :-)

Comment: _"This is not the way Docker is meant to be."_ IMHO a very wrong statement. Docker has by design no limitation of how many processes it can run. It is about isolation of the processes, not limiting the number of processes (it only does information hiding of the other processes of the system, so that the process(es) "in" the container can't see them). You _may_ not want to add too many processes - like running Wordpress with many plugins - but this is not how its meant to be, but how you perhaps meant to use it. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @hakre, That's not what I meant. Custom in docker is to make use of standard images and not create full blown systems (with Python, Redis and MySQL) in 1 Container, but rather separate them in different containers (with standard images) and let the containers work together. At least that's how I see docker. :-)

Comment: @BertC Yes, I see where you're coming from (also edited my comment), but you can use a standard container, just then do a multi-stage build (or even single stage) and benefit from packaging on top of docker-hub. Especially in a build situation, you may want to have a well defined build environment, and given that Docker should not be used in production, it may be fine to be used for build environments. It is much simpler then to cram them all in one container, such a process then is much more well-defined than composing multiple containers first only to get the build env running.